# Replace digits by character in String

Tags: java, regex, char

I want to replace ssn by certain char. for example:

```
public char filter = "a";
public String ssn = 123-45-6789
public replace(string ssn){
    //replace ssn = aaa-aa-aaaa because filter = "a"
}
```

Can anyone give me an idea how to do it since it has "-" inside of the string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to replace only the digits, try the following code:

```
public String replace(string ssn) {
     return ssn.replaceAll("[0-9]", "a");
}
```

The regular expression `[0-9]` defines which characters should be replaced (every "character" between 0 and 9, meaning: only digits).

Answer (score 2):

To use regex with replaceAll(), you need to make your filter a String. As well, you need to return a String in your replace function.
Try the following:

```
String filter = "a";
public String replace(String ssn)
{
    return ssn.replaceAll("[0-9]",filter);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't modify string, since it is immutable class. But you can create new string with replaced values. So

- create `StringBuidler`
- iterate over all characters of ssn (`toCharArray()` can be useful here)

  - if char is digit append `filter` to builder (`Character.isDigit(char)` comes to mind)
  - if char is `-` (or non-digit) append `'-'` to builder
- convert builder toString

You can also try using `replaceAll` and regex which will match only digits.